# Is there a folder for JUST Archived email? NOT ALL MAIL

Tags: gmail

Is there an "Archives" file?  On my old email on my phone, when you swiped left, you deleted it, on Gmail, apparently you are sending it to Archives.  While trying to search for the folder, and follow the instructions I found, I ended up archiving active email I need.  I found it in "All Mail", but why ca I find JUST a list of what is Archived?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to access a label or folder specifically for "Archived" email, you could do the following search in Gmail:

```
-in:inbox
```

This search basically means search for email that is currently "Not in Inbox."

Answer (score 0):

On Gmail archiving an email means removing from Inbox, there isn't an "Archives" view/folder other than All Mail.

Reference

- [Archive or mute Gmail messages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en)